# get xpath following sibling to make use of a template with its value

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt, xpath

I have following XSLT :

```
     <xsl:if test="$CurPos mod 2 =1">
         <li style="width:604px;"> 
           <div class="content-left" style="width:300px; height:290px;float:left;">
                <xsl:if test="string-length($SafeImageUrl) != 0">
                  <div class="images-area-left">
                    <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" target="{$LinkTarget}">
                      <img class="image" src="{$SafeImageUrl}" alt="{@ImageUrlAltText}" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="Heading-desc">
                        <span class="NewsHeading"><h4><xsl:value-of select="@Title"/></h4></span>
                        <span class="Desc">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring(@Comments,0,200)"/>
                            <xsl:if test="string-length(@Comments) &gt; 200">…</xsl:if>
<a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" class="ReadMore"> Read More</a>    
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
               </xsl:if>            
            </div>

            <div class="content-right" style="float:right; width:300px; height:290px;"> 
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]/@PublishingRollupImage" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                <span class="NewsHeading"><h4><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]/@Title"/></h4></span>
                <span class="Desc" style="display:block; width:280px;"><xsl:value-of select="substring(following-sibling::*[1]/@Comments,0,200)"/>
                 <xsl:if test="string-length(following-sibling::*[1]/@Comments) &gt; 200">…</xsl:if><a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" class="ReadMore"> Read More</a>    
                </span>
            </div>
         </li>
     </xsl:if>
```

There is a variable $SafeLinkUrl coming from another template that gets the page URL for the current Row. Since I am getting following sibling while I am still on the current node, I am unable to get the URL for the following sibling.

```
  <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
      <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
```

============> points to this template

```
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
    <xsl:param name="UrlColumnName"/>
    <xsl:if test="$UseCopyUtil = 'True'">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($RootSiteRef,'/_layouts/CopyUtil.aspx?Use=id&amp;Action=dispform&amp;ItemId=',@ID,'&amp;ListId=',@ListId,'&amp;WebId=',@WebId,'&amp;SiteId=',$SiteId,'&amp;Source=',$Source)"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$UseCopyUtil != 'True'">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeStaticUrl">
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="$UrlColumnName"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

and this has a call to ====>

```
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeStaticUrl">
    <xsl:param name="UrlColumnName"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Url">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.FormatColumnIntoUrl">
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="$UrlColumnName"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="cmswrt:EnsureIsAllowedProtocol($Url)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Which again calls another template, on and on =====>

```
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.FormatColumnIntoUrl">
    <xsl:param name="UrlColumnName"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Value" select="@*[name()=$UrlColumnName]"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains($DataColumnTypes,concat(';',$UrlColumnName,',URL;'))">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.FormatValueIntoUrl">
            <xsl:with-param name="Value" select="$Value"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(contains($DataColumnTypes,concat(';',$UrlColumnName,',URL;')))">
        <xsl:value-of select="$Value"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the Actual XML: https://gist.github.com/4380967

XSL for the container: https://gist.github.com/4389989

XSL for the individual Row: https://gist.github.com/4389997

I am unable to use $SafeLinkUrl for the following-sibling::*[1] as it is applicable for current item and not the immediate sibling. How do I make the variable applicable for the sibling too??

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the input XML you are processing with your XSLT? What is the context node for the code you have posted?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4380967

Comment: So, what is the question? I don't see one. What is the source XML document? What is the wanted result? What is the actual result and what is wrong with it? Could you, please, provide a complete, but minimal example with these, so that we can copy + paste in our XSLT IDEs and run the transformation and repro your result? *Then* this would be a good question.

Comment: Sorry Dimitre, I have updated my question with the actual issue and the raw xml and xsl files involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
 <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
   <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::*[1]">
    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
      <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
```

**Or even better, add a second parameter to your template:**

```
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
    <xsl:param name="UrlColumnName"/>
    <xsl:param name="pContext" select="."/>

    <xsl:if test="$UseCopyUtil = 'True'">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($RootSiteRef,'/_layouts/CopyUtil.aspx?Use=id&amp;Action=dispform&amp;ItemId=', $pContext/@ID,'&amp;ListId=',$pContext/@ListId,'&amp;WebId=',$pContext/@WebId,'&amp;SiteId=',$pContext/$SiteId,'&amp;Source=',$Source)"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$UseCopyUtil != 'True'">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeStaticUrl">
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="$UrlColumnName"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Do so for the other two templates. Specify the `$pContext` parameter when calling any of the two inner templates.

Then call the outermost template specifying the `$pContext` parameter as `following-sibling::*[1]`.